# How to test new Button()?

Tags: android, button, junit, powermock

I have some ButtonCreator.class that create Android UI element via models. Have any ideas how to test it?

```
public class ButtonCreator {

    Button createWidget(ButtonComponent buttonComponent, Context context) {
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(buttonComponent.getText());

        return button;
    }
}
```

I wrote a test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Button.class, Context.class, ButtonCreator.class})
public class CreaterButtonTest {

    @Mock
    Context mContext;
    @Mock
    Button mButton;

    @Test
    public void createWidget() { 
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Button.class).withAnyArguments(). thenReturn(mButton);

        ButtonCreator buttonCreator = new ButtonCreator();
        ButtonComponent buttonComponent = new ButtonComponent();
        buttonComponent.setText("someText");

        Button buttonActual = buttonCreator.createWidget(buttonComponent, mContext);

        assertThat(buttonActual.getText(), is("someText"));
    }

}
```

But in buttonActual.getText() I have a null. Help it solve please.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to understand about mocks, is that they will never function as your original object, unless you specify the behavior.

In your case:

The Mocked button will receive the call of setText(), but because it's a Mocked object, it does not have any internal state to store the text string, so it will correctly return null.
You can specify the behavior to return a string with something like:

```
when(mButton.getText()).thenReturn("mytext");
```

But this is not so optional, because in the end you are testing how the mock framework is working.

In these cases, you should use the verify method. Every mock object records all method calls during it's lifetime.

```
verify(mButton, times(1)).setText("someText"));
```

With this you are making sure that the exact method calls are happening.